# React-Redux - failing to show props on view page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> EDIT: Ive changed my return to an object, yet still i'm getting empty props.

console.log of `mapStateToProps(state)` shows that temperature is empty. I am assuming I am getting back a non changed state, temperature from my axios call is not returned to my `weatherPage.js`.

my whole environment is working fine, im just trying to make an axios get request.

I'm having a bit of a difficulty passing my object through the Redux lifecycle, from the actions to the reducer while keeping the `propTypes` validation method and trying to use `Object.assign()` (which is truly the right way of mutating the state with a single deep copy as Dan Abramov noted.)

**The error:**

my props are empty. The axios call I've made in **`src/actions/weatherActions.js`** is not showing up as a `prop.weatherDetails.temperature` in **`src/components/weatherPage.js`**
, it returns my default state.

- I'm new to ES6 and Redux, I've included propTypes into my page and I'm having bit of an issue with this, I think the issue comes from supplying the right state that comes from the action.
- When the choose button is pressed i'm supposed to receive the temp_c (axios calls **[this json](https://pastebin.com/518sbmqy)**)

**src/components/weatherPage.js**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import * as WeatherActions from '../../actions/weatherActions';

class WeatherPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>temps: {this.props.weatherDetails.temperature}</h2>
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={this.onClickSave.bind(this)}
                    value="CHOOSE"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    onClickSave() {
        WeatherActions.getWeather(this.props.dispatch);
    }


WeatherPage.propTypes = {
    weatherDetails: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired

};


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        weatherDetails: state.weathers.weatherDetails
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(WeatherPage));
```

- Since `this.props.weatherDetails.temperature` shows my current state, I know that problem lies between the action and the reducer.

**src/actions/weatherActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ActionTypes = {
    WEATHER: { LOAD_WEATHER: 'WEATHER.LOAD_WEATHER' } };

export function getWeather(dispatch) {
    console.log('in getWeather method');
    console.log('this is getWeather dispatch: ', dispatch);

    axios({
        url: 'http://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/trigger/32.08,34.78/current%20temperature%20gt%2016%20includecurrent?app_id=ba2f68f0&app_key=0356747cc4d1d4ba0dd5cc25a0c86743',
            method: 'get'
            }).then(function (response) {
                //console.log('in the then func with this res: ',  JSON.stringify(response));
                dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.WEATHER.LOAD_WEATHER,
                    temperature: response.CurrentWeather.temp_c
                },
                    function () {
                    console.log('dispatch completed');

                    });
            });
    console.log('end of class getWeather');
```

- I'm performing a simple axios call, yet i'm not sure if i'm dispatching the *'payload'* (`temperature: response.CurrentWeather.temp_c`) correctly to appear through the reducer and back into view.

Here is my reducer:

**src/reducers/weatherReducer.js**

```
import * as WeatherActions from '../actions/weatherActions';

const initialState = {
    weatherDetails: {
        area: '',
        temperature: 'sdf'
    }
};

function WeatherReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log('in WeatherReducer, this is action: ' + JSON.stringify(action));


    switch (action.type) {
        case WeatherActions.ActionTypes.WEATHER.LOAD_WEATHER:
            return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.temperature.data)];
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
export default WeatherReducer;
```

What am I missing here on this build?

Comment: This is the problem (array, not object) : `return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.temperature.data)];`

Comment: @wesley6j how would you write it? Shubham Khatri tried to but that 's an error.

Answer (score 1):

You state object must be returned as an object rather than an array from the reducer like

```
switch (action.type) {
        case WeatherActions.ActionTypes.WEATHER.LOAD_WEATHER:
            return  Object.assign({}, state, action.temperature.data);
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

Comment: ESlint is warning "UNEXPECTED TOKEN" on `return {...state, Object.assign({}, action.temperature.data)};`

Comment: your return statement is not allowed, it doesn't let me return an object like you coded.
I get unexpected token

Comment: Don't know where my mind is today, I completely forgot the state argument

Comment: you solved one issue, but now I can't seem to see my response from weather, prop.weatherDetails.temperature is empty.. it's still taking the old state after clicking the button.

Comment: Can you see what is logged by `state.weathers.weatherDetails` in mapStateToProps method

Comment: an object with two empty fields, temperature and area.

Comment: when we return object from reducer like `return  Object.assign({}, state, action.temperature.data);` make sure that the data `action.temperature.data `has your desired result